# AT command for disable Radio Signal Strength Indication and alike?

Tags: gsm, at-command, rssi

Im working on a program to send and recieve SMS using a GSM modem and my computer.

I have gotten sending and receiving to work - well sort of.

Once in a while my program is sent into a total chrash due to modem is mixing up information about Radio Signal Strength Indication and alike, while also serving my program with the hex code for the message.

My code can handle the hex code just fine. but I have seen the following line popup while im decoding a byte stream:

```
^RSSI: 2
```

So far I've seen it send out values between 1 and 10.

Is there an AT Command that can disable them? I have no need for them.

Or alternative: Is there a general syntax for them, so I can filter them out before decoding?

Im leaning towards a filter solution. But that would be more easy to implement if I knew whenever modem is sending out on the form: "^SOMETHING: xxx", then It would be nice to know if it is always followed up be a delimiter say for instance "\r".

Comment: Which modem manufacturer / model do you have?

Comment: Im using Huawei E173.

Sorry for the long time in answer - guss my notification went in spam trap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try turning off periodic messages as using AT^CURC=0.

Information regarding the AT^CURC command:

> AT^CURC? Current setting of periodic status messages
>
> AT^CURC=? See what you possible values are
>
> AT^CURC=0 turn off periodic status messages

Comment: Have a PuTTY session running for a while now. And AT^CURC command did the trick!

PuTTY is very quiet now. ;-)

Comment: Thanks.
This parameter At^curc=0 stopps my modem to hopping from wcdma to hsdpa and vice-versa incessantly. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The best way to tackle this scenario would be to replace that part of the response with an empty string because otherwise, it will be difficult to check even if the command sent to disable it is working or not.

This regex will match all those. You can replace them ideally by an empty string.

```
(\\n|\\r|\\r\\n)\\^.*(\\n|\\r|\\r\\n)
```